# How to change the width of the editing form dynamically?

Tags: jqgrid

Under some circumstances I need to enlarge the edit and add form dialog in jqgrid.

I tried with

```
$("#contratos").jqGrid('navGrid', '#paginacion', {}, {width: 900});
```

Without success.

I am using JQGrid 4.5.2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To set `width` for **both** edit and add dialogs you should use

```js
$("#contratos").jqGrid('navGrid', '#paginacion', {}, {width: 900}, {width: 900});
```

or

```js
var formEditOptions = { width: 900 };
...
$("#contratos").jqGrid('navGrid', '#paginacion', {}, formEditOptions, formEditOptions);
```

Such settings will still work *not dynamically* (see the title of your question). One can use `beforeShowForm` callback instead:

```js
var formEditOptions = {
        beforeShowForm: function ($form) {
            $form.closest(".ui-jqdialog").width(500);
        }
    };
...
$("#contratos").jqGrid('navGrid', '#paginacion', {}, formEditOptions, formEditOptions);
```

Finally I'd recommend you to consider to upgrade from the retro version 4.5.2 to the current version of [free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid) (the version 4.13.6). The version 4.5.2 was published almost 4 years ago (21 May 2013) at the time of Chrome 26, Firefox 21, IE 10. One uses now Chrome 55, Firefox 50, Edge 38 and IE 11. I'd recommend you to try free jqGrid 4.13.6 by loading jqGrid files directly from CDN (see [the wiki article](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/wiki/Access-free-jqGrid-from-different-CDNs)).

Comment: Thanks..... I have finaly just used $form.closest(".ui-jqdialog").width(500); in beforeShowForm event I already have for my edit form.